# Retrieve post of a Facebook page using Facebook API (python)

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Currently, I am using https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk

I just picked up python not too long ago.

**What i need to do**:
Retrieve posts of a particular Facebook page.

Example:

At Facebook Graph Explorer API, using walmart as an example

/v2.2/`walmart?fields=posts{message}`

The result is what I needed.

**What I have**

Following the example from [the get_post.py example](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/blob/master/examples/get_posts.py)

```
targetProfile = 'walmart'
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(key)
profile = graph.get_object(targetProfile)
posts = graph.get_connections(profile['id'], 'posts')

print posts['data']
```

After running the above code with valid access key, etc., it seems to print out comments/post of consumer but I only need the posts from walmart. Can someone enlighten me as to what i should do, or what I did wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some trial and errors, i found the solution to my answer. This might not be the best solution but it fulfill my requirement.

```
profile = graph.get_object(targetProfile+"/statuses")

Jstr = json.dumps(profile)
JDict = json.loads(Jstr)

   for i in JDict['data']:
       print "message: "+i['message']
```

Answer (score 1):

The Below snippet should solve your issue regarding retrieving all the messages for posts, It uses [facepy](https://github.com/jgorset/facepy) and handles paging on its own.

```
from facepy import GraphAPI
import json

access = '<access_token>'

graph = GraphAPI(access)
page_id= '<page_name or page_id>'
datas= graph.get(page_id+'/posts?fields=message', page=True, retry=5)

posts=[]

for data in datas:
    posts.append(data)
    print posts
```

Answer (score 0):

`profile = graph.get_object(targetProfile+"/statuses")
print profile['data'][0]['message']`

this will return te first message of your profile, without using JStr and JDict var