# get a list of posts by keyword using Facebook API[python]

Tags: facebook, python-3.x

**Hello everybody.**
I am using the Facebook SDK for Python,i want to know how can i get a list of posts by keyword using Facebook API?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve post of a Facebook page using Facebook API (python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26857767/retrieve-post-of-a-facebook-page-using-facebook-api-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed/

> Access to the Public Feed API is restricted to a limited set of media publishers and usage requires prior approval by Facebook. You cannot apply to use the API at this time.